# Get deceleration (negative acceleration when apply brake force)

Tags: esp32, mpu6050

I want to build a device to measure deceleration force when a car brakes. I am using a MPU6050 for get data and I read from it acceleration on X,Y,Z axes in m/s2 and also it gives me gyro in degrees/second.
My question is how can I use these gyro values to correct acceleration? Basically when apply brake the position of the axes are changing .
Also I guess I need to calculate the deviation as well if the car goes to the left or right during brake process.
Any ideas, hints will be very appreciated
Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly you want to calculate? Deceleration is indeed a negative number defined as `deceleration = (velocity@begin - velocity@final)/time`.

Comment: I accelerate to some speed for example. After that I will have a time without acceleration and when apply brake I start record values till the car is stopped. Then I want to get the speed that was when I started to brake and the distance till the car was stopped